# _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value) - Flutter 2.8.1

Tags: mobile, flutter

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo em flutter para ver e comprar moedas, mas antes mesmo de conseguir entrar na moeda selecionada para simular a compra o aplicativo dá um erro na parte de verificação. No momento não estou usando nenhuma api, criei apenas uma classe com algumas informações apenas para indo desenvolver o layout do app.

Informações das moedas:

```
import 'package:flutter_aula_1/models/moeda.dart';

class MoedaRepository {
  static List<Moeda> tabela = [
    Moeda(
      icone: 'images/bitcoin.png',
      nome: 'Bitcoin',
      sigla: 'BTC',
      preco: 265515.56,
    ),
    Moeda(
      icone: 'images/ethereum.png',
      nome: 'Ethereum',
      sigla: 'ETH',
      preco: 20824.77,
    ),
    Moeda(
      icone: 'images/xrp.png',
      nome: 'XRP',
      sigla: 'XRP',
      preco: 4.69,
    ),
    Moeda(
      icone: 'images/cardano.png',
      nome: 'Cardano',
      sigla: 'ADA',
      preco: 7.58,
    ),
    Moeda(
      icone: 'images/usdcoin.png',
      nome: 'USD Coin',
      sigla: 'USDC',
      preco: 5.56,
    ),
    Moeda(
      icone: 'images/litecoin.png',
      nome: 'Litecoin',
      sigla: 'LTC',
      preco: 831.74,
    ),
  ];
}
```

Página que mostra as moedas para serem selecionadas:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_aula_1/models/moeda.dart';
import 'package:flutter_aula_1/repositories/moeda_repository.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

import 'moedas_detalhes_page.dart';

class MoedasPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MoedasPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MoedasPage> createState() => _MoedasPageState();
}

class _MoedasPageState extends State<MoedasPage> {
  //"API"
  final tabela = MoedaRepository.tabela;
  //Formatar as moedas
  NumberFormat real =
      NumberFormat.currency(locale: 'pt_BR', name: 'R\$', decimalDigits: 2);
  //Selecionar moedas
  List<Moeda> selecionadas = [];
  //Favoritar moedas
  List<Moeda> favoritas = [];

  appBarDinamica() {
    //Nada selecionado
    if (selecionadas.isEmpty) {
      return AppBar(
        title: const Text('Cripto Moedas'),
        centerTitle: true,
      );
      //Alguma moeda está selecionada
    } else {
      return AppBar(
        //Botão de limpar
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.close),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              selecionadas.clear();
            });
          },
        ),
        //Total de moedas selecionadas
        title: Center(
          child: Text('${selecionadas.length} selecionadas'),
          widthFactor: 0.0,
        ),
        //Centralizar texto
        centerTitle: true,
        //Cor de fundo da appBar
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[50],
        //Sombra da appBar
        elevation: 1.0,
        //Cor do botão
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.black87),
        //Estilo do texto
        toolbarTextStyle: const TextTheme(
          headline6: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ).bodyText2,
        titleTextStyle: const TextTheme(
          headline6: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ).headline6,
      );
    }
  }

  mostrarDetalhes(Moeda index) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => MoedasDetalhesPage(
          moeda: index,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBarDinamica(),
      body: ListView.separated(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ListTile(
            //Icone
            leading: (selecionadas.contains(tabela[index]))
                ? const CircleAvatar(
                    child: Icon(Icons.check),
                  )
                : SizedBox(
                    child: Image.asset(tabela[index].icone),
                    width: 40,
                  ),
            //Nome
            title: Text(
              tabela[index].nome,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 17.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              ),
            ),
            //Sigla
            subtitle: Text(tabela[index].sigla),
            //Valor
            trailing: Text(
              real.format(tabela[index].preco),
            ),
            //Selecionada
            selected: selecionadas.contains(tabela[index]),
            //Cor do background quando selecionado
            selectedTileColor: Colors.indigo[50],
            //Shape de quando for selecionado
            shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(12.0),
              ),
            ),
            //Selecionar moeda
            onLongPress: () {
              setState(() {
                if (selecionadas.contains(tabela[index])) {
                  selecionadas.remove(tabela[index]);
                } else {
                  selecionadas.add(tabela[index]);
                }
              });
            },
            onTap: () => mostrarDetalhes(tabela[index]),
          );
        },
        //Espaçamento interno
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        //Divisor
        separatorBuilder: (_, __) => const Divider(),
        //Tamanho máximo da lista
        itemCount: tabela.length,
      ),
      //Botão de favoritar
      floatingActionButton: selecionadas.isNotEmpty
          ? FloatingActionButton.extended(
              onPressed: () {},
              label: const Text(
                'FAVORITAR',
                style: TextStyle(
                  letterSpacing: 0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              icon: const Icon(Icons.star),
            )
          : null,
      //Local do botão de favoritar
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    );
  }
}
```

Página que deveria mostrar os detalhes e simular a compra mas dá erro:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import 'package:flutter_aula_1/models/moeda.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class MoedasDetalhesPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MoedasDetalhesPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.moeda,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Moeda moeda;

  @override
  _MoedasDetalhesPageState createState() => _MoedasDetalhesPageState();
}

class _MoedasDetalhesPageState extends State<MoedasDetalhesPage> {
  //Formatar as moedas
  NumberFormat real =
      NumberFormat.currency(locale: 'pt_BR', name: 'R\$', decimalDigits: 2);

  //Chave do formulário
  final _form = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  //Pegar valor
  final _valor = TextEditingController();

  //Quantidade de moedas que posso comprar
  double quantidade = 0;

  //Função que realiza a compra
  comprar() {
    //O erro aparece aqui, no ponto de exclamação
    if (_form.currentState!.validate()) {
      // Salvar a comprar
      Navigator.pop(context);

      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(content: Text('Compra realizade com sucesso')),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.moeda.nome),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            //Informações da moeda
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 24.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    child: Image.asset(widget.moeda.icone),
                    width: 50.0,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 10.0,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    real.format(widget.moeda.preco),
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      fontSize: 26.0,
                      color: Colors.grey[800],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            //Quanto dessa moeda posso comprar
            (quantidade > 0)
                ? SizedBox(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: Container(
                      child: Text(
                        '${quantidade.toString()} ${widget.moeda.sigla}',
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                          color: Colors.teal,
                        ),
                      ),
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 24.0),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.teal.withOpacity(0.05),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                : Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 24.0),
                  ),
            //Input
            Form(
              key: _form,
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: _valor,
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
                //Decoração
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  //Borda em volta
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  //Label
                  labelText: 'Valor',
                  //Icone que vem antes do valor
                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.monetization_on_outlined,
                  ),
                  //Texto que vem depois do valor
                  suffix: Text(
                    'reais',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                //Tipo do teclado
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                //Aceitar apenas numero
                inputFormatters: [
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                ],
                //Validação
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Informe o valor da compra';
                  } else if (double.parse(value) < 50) {
                    return 'Compra mínima é R\$ 50,00';
                  } else {
                    return null;
                  }
                },
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    quantidade = (value.isEmpty)
                        ? 0
                        : double.parse(value) / widget.moeda.preco;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            //Botão
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 24.0),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: comprar(),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: const [
                    Icon(Icons.check),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                      child: Text(
                        'Comprar',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Qual é a mensagem de erro que aparece para ti?

Comment: Dentro do objetivo do site é importante [edit] a pergunta e reduzir o código a um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O sinal de exclamação `!` é um operador que verifica se a variável é nula, e se for nula, dispara esse erro. É um operador que deve ser usado com cautela, quando se tem certeza que nunca será nulo. Existem outras alternativas para manusear esse erro sem gerar um crash para o usuário (como oferecer um valor padrão caso a variável seja nula, ou então verificar antes e caso for nula tomar outras providências).

Essa propriedade `currentState` representa a classe de estado que contém o Widget a que essa `key` foi atribuída. Se essa chave não está em widget nenhum, essa propriedade é nula.

Porém, logo abaixo pode-se ver que você atribuiu ao widget `Form`:

```
Form(
              key: _form,
```

Então, o erro ocorre porque a linha de verificação está sendo chamada **antes** da linha que a chave é atribuída ao widget. Essa verificação está dentro do método `comprar`, e ao ver aonde esse método `comprar` é usado, podemos encontrar o erro:

Isto é, aonde está:

`onPressed: comprar(),`

deveria estar:

`onPressed: comprar,`

Quando escrevemos o nome de um método com parênteses, estamos *chamando* a função e passando seu retorno como parâmetro, o que é diferente de passar o método *em si* como parâmetro, que era sua intenção.

Para uma leitura complementar, sugiro pesquisar sobre os tópicos de `null-safety` e chamada de funções. Existe a documentação oficial [aqui](https://dart.dev/null-safety) e [aqui](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour) (em inglês), mas existem respostas boas aqui mesmo no StackOverflow em português sobre esses tópicos.